# slim class ruby code

Tags: html, ruby, slim-lang

I have slim html `.slide-1.bg-image.bg-pattern`
and want to do dynamic number of slide slide-2,slide-3, through ruby `each`
im try to do like this

```
-@user.listings.each_with_index do |l,index |
    .slide-"#{index}".bg-image.bg-pattern
```

but have got an syntax error

How to make it properly?

Comment: What's does the syntax error say?

Answer (score 1):

```
-@user.listings.each_with_index do |l,index |
  .bg-image.bg-pattern class="slide-#{index}"
```